# Generate waveforms for audio files with large amount of channels

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, waveform

I want to generate .png files displaying the waveforms of interleaved audio .wav files using the FFmpeg libraries. http://ffmpeg.org/documentation.html

If the interleaved audio file contains maximum 8 channels, I manage to successfully achieve this using the following command line:

```
ffmpeg -i 8_channels_input.wav -y -filter_complex "showwavespic=s=1920x1200:split_channels=1" -frames:v 1 8_channels_waveform_output.png
```

However, if the interleaved audio file contains more than 8 channels, FFmpeg gives the following:

> Input #0, wav, from '30_channels_input.wav':   Duration: 00:00:02.08,
> bitrate: 31752 kb/s   Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_s24le ([1][0][0][0] /
> 0x0001), 44100 Hz, 30 channels, s32 (24 bit), 31752 kb/s Stream
> mapping:   Stream #0:0 (pcm_s24le) -> showwavespic   showwavespic ->
> Stream #0:0 (png) Press [q] to stop, [?] for help [auto_resampler_0 @
> 0x7faf5d60a3c0] Cannot select channel layout for the link between
> filters auto_resampler_0 and Parsed_showwavespic_0. [auto_resampler_0
> @ 0x7faf5d60a3c0] Unknown channel layouts not supported, try
> specifying a channel layout using 'aformat=channel_layouts=something'.
> Error reinitializing filters! Failed to inject frame into filter
> network: Invalid argument Error while processing the decoded data for
> stream #0:0 Conversion failed!

Here is the related documentation (c.f. bottom of the page):
https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/AudioChannelManipulation

My problem is:
I need to generate the visual waveforms of audio files containing up to 30 channels.
All my attempts were unsuccessful so far (I am trying to define custom channel layouts and I am not sure if I am on the right track here).

To simplify, I need to complete/modify the following command to make it work:

```
ffmpeg -i 30_channels_input.wav -y -filter_complex "showwavespic=s=1920x1200:split_channels=1" -frames:v 1 30_channels_waveform_output.png
```

[EDIT] Remarks:

I manage to generate the waveforms of a 10 channels input by combining existing layouts:

```
ffmpeg -i 10_channels_input.wav -y -filter_complex "aformat=channel_layouts=7.1+downmix, showwavespic=s=1920x1200:split_channels=1" -frames:v 1 10_channels_waveform_output.png
```

However, if you attempt to do it for a 30 channels input by combining 5x 6.0 layouts:

```
ffmpeg -i 30_channels_input.wav -y -filter_complex "aformat=channel_layouts=6.0+6.0+6.0+6.0+6.0, showwavespic=s=1920x1200:split_channels=1" -frames:v 1 30_channels_waveform_output.png
```

FFmpeg gives the following:

> [auto_resampler_0 @ 0x7ffd7002a480] [SWR @ 0x7ffd7013a000] Rematrix is
> needed between 30 channels and 6.0 but there is not enough information
> to do it [auto_resampler_0 @ 0x7ffd7002a480] Failed to configure
> output pad on auto_resampler_0 Error reinitializing filters! Failed to
> inject frame into filter network: Invalid argument Error while
> processing the decoded data for stream #0:0

My assumption is that I need to create a custom layout using 30 unique channel IDs (c.f. https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/AudioChannelManipulation bottom of the page) instead of combining existing layouts.

It seems that only 25 channel IDs are available though. Creating a custom layout with 30 channels is maybe not possible at all...

[EDIT 2] Remarks:

I finally found the documentation I was looking for. But it still seems that generating the waveforms of 30 channels would be difficult.

Here is how to create custom layouts:
https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-utils.html

> A custom channel layout can be specified as a sequence of terms,
> separated by ’+’ or ’|’. Each term can be:
>
> the name of a standard channel layout (e.g. ‘mono’, ‘stereo’, ‘4.0’,
> ‘quad’, ‘5.0’, etc.) the name of a single channel (e.g. ‘FL’, ‘FR’,
> ‘FC’, ‘LFE’, etc.) a number of channels, in decimal, followed by ’c’,
> yielding the default channel layout for that number of channels (see
> the function av_get_default_channel_layout). Note that not all channel
> counts have a default layout. a number of channels, in decimal,
> followed by ’C’, yielding an unknown channel layout with the specified
> number of channels. Note that not all channel layout specification
> strings support unknown channel layouts. a channel layout mask, in
> hexadecimal starting with "0x" (see the AV_CH_* macros in
> libavutil/channel_layout.h. Before libavutil version 53 the trailing
> character "c" to specify a number of channels was optional, but now it
> is required, while a channel layout mask can also be specified as a
> decimal number (if and only if not followed by "c" or "C").
>
> See also the function av_get_channel_layout defined in
> libavutil/channel_layout.h.

e.g.

Therefore, for 11 channels input:

```
ffmpeg -i 11_channels_input.wav -y -filter_complex "aformat=channel_layouts=FL+FR+FC+BL+BR+BC+SL+SR+WL+WR+TBL, showwavespic=s=1920x1200:split_channels=1" -frames:v 1 11_waveform_output.png
```

--> worked for me

while:

```
ffmpeg -i 11_channels_input.wav -y -filter_complex "aformat=channel_layouts=11c, showwavespic=s=1920x1200:split_channels=1" -frames:v 1 11_waveform_output.png
```

--> does not work

But:

```
ffmpeg -i 24_channels_input.wav -y -filter_complex "aformat=channel_layouts=24c, showwavespic=s=1920x1200:split_channels=1" -frames:v 1 24_waveform_output.png
```

--> does work

and finally, what I am still trying to achieve:

```
ffmpeg -i 30_channels_input.wav -y -filter_complex "aformat=channel_layouts=30c, showwavespic=s=1920x1200:split_channels=1" -frames:v 1 30_waveform_output.png
```

--> does not work

p.s.

- I execute these commands in sub shells via Ruby scripts (puts %x{...})
- My system: macOS 10.15.6 | zsh | FFmpeg 4.4 | Ruby 2.6.3

Comment: Show the complete log from the command with `30_channels_input.wav` input.

Comment: I'd suggest removing the [ruby] and [zsh] tags. Even though you execute `ffmpeg` via ruby, I expect that answers will focus on `ffmpeg` and not ruby/zsh.

Comment: Post edited again. Some progression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Untested workaround is to use pan to choose each channel, a showwavespic per channel, and stack them with vstack:

```
ffmpeg -i input.wav -filter_complex
  "[0:a]pan=mono|c0=c0,showwavespic=s=1920x40[a0];
   [0:a]pan=mono|c0=c1,showwavespic=s=1920x40[a1];
   ...
   [0:a]pan=mono|c0=c29,showwavespic=s=1920x40[a29];
   [a0][a1]...[a29]vstack=inputs=30" output.png
```